# Make variable immutable after initial assignment

Tags: swift, immutability

Is there a way to make a variable immutable *after* initializing/assigning it, so that it can change at one point, but later become immutable? I know that I could create a new `let` variable, but is there a way to do so without creating a new variable?

If not, what is best practice to safely ensure a variable isn't changed after it needs to be?
Example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
var x = 0         //VARIABLE DECLARATION


x += 1           //VARIABLE IS CHANGED AT SOME POINT


x = let x        //MAKE VARIABLE IMMUTABLE AFTER SOME FUNCTION IS PERFORMED


x += 5          //what I'm going for: ERROR - CANNOT ASSIGN TO IMMUTABLE VARIABLE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize a variable with an inline closure:

```
let x: Int = {
    var x = 0

    while x < 100 {
        x += 1
    }

    return x
}()
```

Comment: While this sort of solves the example given, I'm struggling to see it's real-world  benefit, as it still initialises the variable in a single action to a pre-determined value, and it can't be used prior to this or modified in any different way.  This to me is the same as just `let x = 100` but using more code.  What am I missing?

Comment: @flanker in real world you can have more complex calculations, which cannot be reduced to a constant that easily.

Comment: Oh agreed, and do it all the time, esp for UI. I meant in the context of the question where I read it as wanting to initialise it to a value (0 above), change it at some indeterminate later point (to 100 in the example), and then make it immutable.  But OP seems happy with your answer so I guess I'm misreading the question's intent.  Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way I know of that lets you change a `var` variable into a `let` constant later on. But you *could* declare your constant as `let` to begin with and not immediately give it a value.

```
let x: Int /// No initial value

x = 100 /// This works.

x += 5 /// Mutating operator '+=' may not be used on immutable value 'x'
```

As long as you assign a value to your constant sometime before you use it, you're fine, since the compiler can figure out that it will eventually be populated. For example `if else` works, since one of the conditional branches is guaranteed to get called.

```
let x: Int

if 5 < 10 {
    x = 0 /// This also works.
} else {
    x = 1 /// Either the first block or the `else` will be called.
}

x += 5 /// Mutating operator '+=' may not be used on immutable value 'x'
```